# SELECT returns different id from what appears to be in my DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I am trying to create a table and insert a few data in it. First things first, I know `.run` is async, so I guess there is no prob since I have them inside the `.get` otherwise I know would get the error that the table doesn't exist on the first part of the code.

So where is my problem; I am inserting a few data into the table, and when I view it with a DB browser on my PC, everything appears fine!, but, when I run the code the row.uid, returned with the `SELECT` is not the one that's in the array.

I dont know if it matters but the uid I am trying to insert is a long integer, like: `212545136172336003` but instead I get back `212545136172336000`, notice how the `3` is now `0` at the end. I am using the sqlite3 module.

```
var my_array = [uid1,uid2...];

db.serialize(function() {
    db.run(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (uid LONG PRIMARY KEY, value1 INTEGER, value2 INTEGER, value3 INTEGER)`);
    my_array.forEach(id => {
        db.get(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid='${id}'; `, (err, row) => {
            if(row == undefined) db.run(`INSERT INTO users (uid, value1, value2, value3) VALUES ('${id}',0,0,0)`);
            if(err) return;
        });
    });
});

//...

function my_f(uid, callback)
{
    db.get(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid='${uid}';`, function(error, row) {
        console.log(row.uid) // <----
        if(row == undefined){ 
            db.run(`INSERT INTO users (uid, value1, value2, value3) VALUES ('${uid}',0,0,0)`);
            return callback([uid,0,0,0]);
        }
        if(error) return;
        return callback([row.uid, row.value1, row.value2, row.value3]);
    });
}
```

Comment: javascript has a `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` `9007199254740991`... you've exceeded it about 25 fold

Comment: Okay so if I want to insert a number thats bigger than that what should I do?

Comment: I am aware of the option making that value a string, and using it like that, but I dont think thats efficient at all.

Comment: What is wrong with making the UID a string?  Java's `UUID` includes non numbers.  Do you plan on doing arithmetic with this UID?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `Java` !== `javascript`

Comment: No but if I have a few thousands of such ids, searching for strings instead of numbers, wouldn't it be slower?

Comment: @JaromandaX You misunderstand my comment.  I am making the argument that in general UIDs don't have to be numbers, hence there is no reason to not use string in JS.  Wait...Java and JavaScript aren't the same thing?

Comment: with a range of -2^53 to 2^53  you'll run out of storage before you run out of numbers

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - was that sarcasm :p

Comment: I know with some db's if you pass a string where the db expects a number, the string will be converted to a number by the db - try `"212545136172336003"` etc

Comment: nope the same thing happened, it does work though if I make my uid a string, should I? again since I'll have a table with a few thousands how slower would that be?, I know I can benchmark it but am asking in case you you know.